# Can I configure Compass to write into separate directories based on the environment or output_style?

Tags: compass-sass

Using Compass, is it possible to define two directories to compile to based upon the `environment` or `output_style` variables in the config.rb?

For example, I'd like to have two directories:

- `/css/`
- `/css/dev/`

When Compass' configured `environment` is set to `:production`, it will compile style into `/css/`. However, when the `environment` is set to `:development`, it would compile style into `/css/dev/`.

Likewise, would it be possible to the same thing based on the `output_style` option? For example, if it is `:expanded` it would compile to the production directory and when it is `:compressed` it would compile to the development directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using conditional statements:

```
if output_style == :expanded
  environment = :development
  css_dir = 'css/dev'
  sass_options = { :debug_info => true }
else
  environment = :production
  css_dir = 'css'
end
```